# Remove trailing ]> from the page

Tags: html, validation, xhtml

I'm using a doctype with custom attributes to validate XHTML. Here is my Doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"
[
<!ATTLIST div data-localized CDATA #IMPLIED> 
]>
```

But the problem is that it's displaying "]>" when I load my page on the browser. The XHTML validates fine.

Comment: I'm not any sort of expert at this stuff, but it looks to me like your code is invalid, because you have nested <>'s. I'd guess the second > is closing the first <, which leaves the last > dangling.

Comment: It validates when I check with W3validator

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in your post. It seems it's also validating in your web browser.  But just because it's syntactically correct doesn't mean it does what you want.

Comment: Seems to be a browser problem and no quirks for it (http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/dtd.html)

Comment: posted a workaround, see below. defeats the purpose of standards, but at least your page will look good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the article in [A list apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/customdtd/) -

> Unfortunately, when you display the
>   file in a browser, the ]> shows up on
>   the screen.

It points out a solution that involves using a separate DTD file (which will fail in W3C validator...)

Answer (score 2):

Workaround would be to remove it using javascript. Add the script after your body declaration e.g.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

 function removeFirstTwo() {
  try {
     var htmlBody = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
     if (htmlBody.firstChild.nodeValue.substr(0,2) == "]>") {
       htmlBody.firstChild.nodeValue = "";
     }
   } catch(e) { 
     //do nothing 
   }
 }

 removeFirstTwo();

</script>
...
```